# How can I return the range spreadsheet in the same form as in the that it is become row by row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a beginner in programming.
I do a query to the spreadsheet in cell A2, then I filter data according to request and receive desired range “I1:L16”.Then I return the data to the tablet. Everything is fine back on the tablet,but it is uncomfortable to read, no line breaks!
Please tell me how can I return the range "I1:L16" in the same form as in the spreadsheet that it is became row by row .

My script

```
function doGet(e)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1UBKi7VDo1aJjn6IwGMKvlxy4Jz9d9jVdY79zpOrkQP8");
  sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(e.parameter.p1) ;
  var n= sheet.getRange("I1:L16").getValues();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(n);
}
```

Spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UBKi7VDo1aJjn6IwGMKvlxy4Jz9d9jVdY79zpOrkQP8/edit?usp=sharing

URL Web applications: sample query
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyHu7d5djciltlG-micI6O-cQheC6kN7yWKkevm5KwGCJiKROZB/exec?p1=1234567891118

Best regards, Alexander.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
function doGet(e)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1UBKi7VDo1aJjn6IwGMKvlxy4Jz9d9jVdY79zpOrkQP8");
  sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(e.parameter.p1) ;
  var n= sheet.getRange("I1:L16").getValues();
  var retStr =""
  for(var i = 0 ; i< n.length ; i++){ 
   retStr += n[i].join("\t") +"\n" //Insert a tab between each element and newline at each row
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(retStr);
}
```

**Edit: Alternative/Robust option**

The better option is to service a Html content, that way you can make use of Html tag to improve presentation of your data.
In the below data I am assuming you want to highlight row 6, you do that using css element to make the text red and bold. 
Code:

```
function doGet(e)
    {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1UBKi7VDo1aJjn6IwGMKvlxy4Jz9d9jVdY79zpOrkQP8");
      sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(e.parameter.p1) ;
      var n= sheet.getRange("I1:L16").getValues();
      var retStr ="<style> .tcol { font-weight: bold; color : red; } </style> <table>"
      for(var i = 0 ; i< n.length ; i++){
       if ( i != 5) { //I assuming row 6 is what you want to highlight
        retStr +="<tr><td>"+ n[i].join("</td><td>") +"</td></tr>"
       } else {
        retStr +="<tr><td class = 'tcol'>" + n[i].join("</td><td class = 'tcol'>") +"</td></div></tr>"
       }

      }
      retStr += "</table>"
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(retStr) 
     }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Dear Jack!
Thank you very much for your quick answer!
it is just what i need.
Can I highlight or change the color of font of found position in the range when you return (in the spreadsheet identified by color)
 
Best regards, Alexander.

Comment: @AlexanderBaskakov I have modified the above code, to show how to highlight a particular row. However, you will need to know which row to highlight, to begin with. getValues() from the spreadsheet gives no information about the color of the cell. You have use some other function like [range.getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getBackgrounds()) to determine the row that has a different background color and corresponding highlight that row.