# How to add to the results of delivery the images from range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a beginner in programming .
There is a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178931/how-can-i-return-the-range-spreadsheet-in-the-same-form-as-in-the-that-it-is-bec) which returns the found range of values by highlighting the desired row. author @Jack Brown.
I made small additions. Here is a script with which I'm working now.
The question: how to add to the delivery of the text ("N1:V15") images from the range(“ W3:W17”)?
[that's the expected result](http://joxi.ru/Y2Lj5eMI9GjkNr)
Thank you!

```
function doGet(e)
    {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1siy44rpMtdLmcCMUiopQ__Z13KkFnB_HMJhiJ_Qv0QY");
      sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(e.parameter.p1) ;
      var n= sheet.getRange("N1:V15").getValues();
      var h= sheet.getRange("L2").getValue(); //Line number for selection
      var z= sheet.getRange("M2").getValue(); 
      if (z==="#N/A"){return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Code not found");
                   }
    var retStr ="<style> .tcol { font: 10pt arial;font-weight: bold; color : DarkBlue; } </style> <table>"
      for(var i = 0 ; i< n.length ; i++){
       if ( i != h) {
        retStr +="<tr><td>"+ n[i].join("</td><td>") +"</td></tr>"
       } else {
        retStr +="<tr><td class = 'tcol'>" + n[i].join("</td><td class = 'tcol'>") +"</td></div></tr>"
       }

      }
      retStr += "</table>"

        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(retStr)
      }
```

Spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1siy44rpMtdLmcCMUiopQ__Z13KkFnB_HMJhiJ_Qv0QY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please be more specific. Are those the URLs of images that you store in a spreadsheet? Building HTML pages from a string is not the best solution as you can create well-structured templates using HtmlService.

Comment: @Anton Dementiev I corrected my question.
It is true, URL of the images are in the range W3-W17 of the same sheet.
that's the expected result http://joxi.ru/Y2Lj5eMI9GjkNr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the example of a simple web app that I put together to demonstrate advanced templating in GAS. For simplicity, the spreadsheet used as a source of image urls contains a single column

[image]

1) Add html template to your GAS project. You create html files via File -> New -> Html file. I called the file 'images'.

2)In your doGet() function, retrieve the array of values from the spreadsheet, then attach it to your template object as property. This will allow you to reference the variable directly from html. Calling evaluate() on the template will execute inline code and build htmlOutput that gets sent to the browser.

```
function doGet(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(yourId);
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
var urls = range.getValues();

var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('images');
template.urls = urls;

return template.evaluate();


}
```

3) For your html file, use scriptlets to dynamically create as many table cells as your array has values. More on templating here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>

    <tr><th>Images</th></tr>

    <?

    for(var i=0; i < urls.length; i++ ) { ?>

    <tr>

     <? for(var j=0; j < urls[i].length; j++) { ?>  

    <td> <img src="<?=urls[i][j]?>" /> </td>


    <?}?>

     </tr>
   <? }

    ?>

    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

4) Deploy your script as a web app. The result is below

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the example , It is very convenient to use! I added the variable in a code of the text part 
var range = sheet.getRange("B1:F" + sheet.getLastRow());
var str = range.getValues() and added a loop in HTML ,it worked ! 

I have a question: how to change the color of the desired row , for example  the 3rd in this range?
Thank you

Comment: Declare the Range object for that row, then call the setBackground(color) method on it https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackground(String). If my reply resolved your issue, please mark it as resolved. Also, please limit your questions to one per post.

Comment: Thanks but the question sounded a bit different!) joxi.ru/Y2Lj5eMI9GjkNr

Comment: @AlexanderBaskakov Sounds like you just want others to do all the coding for you. StackOverflow is a place to ask questions that are reasonably universal. Consider hiring someone

Comment: I agree with you! I will study the documentation and forum. Thank you very much!