# How can I change the color of a string in a range when outputting values to an html file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good afternoon! How can I change the color of a string, for example, number 5 when returning to HTML?
I looked at the documentation, I could not repeat it with my example.

Best regards, Alexander

```
function doGet(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:F" + sheet.getLastRow());
var strn = range.getValues()
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('string');
template.strn = strn;

return template.evaluate();
}
```

string.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>


    <?

    for(var i=0; i < strn.length; i++ ) { ?>

    <tr>

     <? for(var j=0; j < strn[i].length; j++) { ?>  

    <td> <?=strn[i][j]?> </td>


    <?}?>

     </tr>
   <? }

    ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Example result

Comment: setFontColor is for within cells of the Spreadsheet not an HTML output, you'll have to create the HTML to do it

Comment: @ Robin GertenbachI changed the question. I just need to select an arbitrary line with the color

Comment: The question is not GAS-related. HTML styling in done via CSS. Set the 'color' property of the 'style' attribute in the HTML tag that contains the text. For example, <p style="color:red"> Text </p>

Comment: @AntonDementiev Anton hello! I understand correctly that in this case I will not be able to change the color of the desired line (change dynamically), as in this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592067 ?

Comment: Utlimately, this boils down to how you design your app. With HTML and JS, you've got lots of tools at your disposal to achieve this result. You need to look into navigating DOM and writing client-side JS. W3Schools would be a good starting point

Comment: @Anton Dementiev Thank you for everything you get is not so simple! We will study). Alexandre